# Windows 10 — no ethernet connection after the first boot

Tags: windows, windows-10, ethernet, windows-10-v1703, windows-10-v1709

Windows 10 Pro (1703 as well as 1709): after the first boot of the day there is no ethernet connection. The problem dissapears and everything works just fine after a reboot or after disabling of "fast boot" option in system settings.

Is there any other solution for this annoying problem?

…

[image]

Here is the error:

> Beim Start des Geräts
> PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1502&SUBSYS_849C1043&REV_05\3&11583659&0&C8 ist ein
> Problem aufgetreten.
>
> Treibername: net1ic64.inf
>
> Klassen-GUID: {4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
>
> Dienst: e1iexpress
>
> Untere Filter:
>
> Obere Filter:
>
> Problem: 0xA
>
> Problemstatus: 0xC00000C0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try turning off power management option of LAN Adapter as shown in this image (CLEAR checkbox where red circled):

[image: relevant window]

- Try updating your LAN driver.
  I can advise a third party network driver package utility named "3DP Net" (not to be confused with their other product named "3DP Chip").

Every time I've downloaded it (more than 100 times since last 3 years), that package was virus/badware free, but always be cautious on what you install on your device.

[Click to get 3DP Net download page](http://www.3dpchip.com/3dpchip/3dp/net_down_en.php).

Comment: Thanks! But power management option doesn't help if fast boot is enabled.